# Color issue with Plot

Tags: plotting, physics

I would like to print different graphs, and print them in different colors. However, when I use the common way to write it, it doesn't work.

For my project (physics electronic), I have created two functions as shown below. I would like to separately color the graphs.

So that is the function that I wrote:

```
GainPlot[F_, {w_, wmin_, wmax_}, options_] := 
 LogLinearPlot[20*Log[10, Abs[F]], {w, wmin, wmax}, options]
```

But when I try to plot the gain of 2 filters, I cannot display both of the colors:

```
GainPlot[{1/(1 + (I w)/1000000), 1/(
  1 + (I w)/1000000 - (17 w^2)/25000000000000)}, {w, 1, 10000000000}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

The plot displays the 2 gains in RED, the last color in the `PlotStyle`. How can I display both colors?

Comment: I would like to show u some prints of my screen, but i donnot know how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common issue, and can be resolved by specifically adding `Evaluate` to the definition:

```
GainPlot[F_, {w_, wmin_, wmax_}, options_] := LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[20*Log[10, Abs[F]]], {w, wmin, wmax}, options]
```

Comment: Thank you man , you saved me! happy new year

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

In addition to using [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) as SHuisman pointed out, use [`BlankNullSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) with options so that there can be any number of options (including none).

```
GainPlot[F_, {w_, wmin_?NumericQ, wmax_?NumericQ}, options___] :=
 LogLinearPlot[
  Evaluate[FullSimplify[20*Log[10, Abs[F]]]], {w, wmin, wmax}, options]

GainPlot[
 {1/(1 + (I w)/1000000), 
  1/(1 + (I w)/1000000 - (17 w^2)/25000000000000)},
 {w, 1, 10000000000}]
```

[image]

```
GainPlot[
 {1/(1 + (I w)/1000000), 1/(1 + (I w)/1000000 - (17 w^2)/25000000000000)},
 {w, 1, 10000000000},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.35, .5}]]
```

[image]